# Online tool to draw saw lines for plywood?

Tags: wood, tools, carpentry, plywood, saw

I want to make some shelves out of plywood which comes in 250x125 cm sizes. Each straight saw cut costs ~$3, so I would like to reuse as many cuts and at the same time fit as many shelves into on board at a time.

The shelves measure:

```
A: 132x9   7 pcs
B: 88*30   7 pcs
C: 71*9    7 pcs
D: 53*26   8 pcs
E: 79*15   1 pcs
F: 153*26  1 pcs
```

**Question**

Is the an online service of some sort where I can draw the rectangles and fit them into the big plywood board?

I guess I could do it in a drawing program, but I have never tried to use one before, so if there exists an online service for this exact problem, then I would prefer that.

Comment: $3 per cut will buy a saw pretty quickly.

Comment: $3 per cut is steep. At most stores around here they'll cut for like 10c each after 3 or so complimentary.

Comment: At $3/cut you could soon buy a membership at your local maker space, and a certification class on the ShopBot.  And then cut a great deal more than straight lines!

Comment: And, at least at Home Depot, they say "no precision cuts", which means if they're within an inch or so they don't want to hear your complaints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search term: **Panel Cut Calcuator**

A few results - most seem to be software to download and run, rather than a website. The first one does claim to work on the website, but I have not tested any of them personally. I think all the ones I'm linking claim to have a free, community, or functional demo version:

http://www.optimalon.com/online_cut_optimizer.htm

http://www.optimizecutter.com

http://www.maxcutsoftware.com

http://www.applicationprogram.net

http://cutlistplus.com

Enjoy.

Comment: I like this answer better than mine! It shows how much difference a key search word makes.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search using The Google shows me that there does not appear to be any online services to cover what I've learned is called Packing Algorithms mathematics. The usual application shows as to be aimed at irregular objects, rather than the regular rectangles you've listed.

On the flip side, there are a couple approaches. If you have installed or are willing to install [SketchUp](http://www.sketchup.com/), you can create rectangles for each piece and position them in the "master" rectangle of the panel size you've provided. There will be some learning curve, but SketchUp is quite easy to learn. It has a built-in help facility as well as hundreds of easy-to-find tutorials on The YouTube.

For an online approach, no more difficult perhaps than SketchUp is to use a program known as [TinkerCad](https://www.tinkercad.com/) which is mostly aimed at 3d modeling, but will work for your purposes. I performed a quick test run with a couple of your numbers.

I placed a cube and "stretched" it to 250 x 125, then "flattened" it to 1mm and positioned it below the modeling plane. I then placed another cube and adjusted the dimensions to 132 x 9 x 3, then created duplicates to cover the quantity you have in your list.

All of this is done manually, of course, but provides a visual assist for your cutting plans.

Please note that you will want to collect the saw kerf dimension of the tool being used to cut the material. Saw kerf is the material removed by the saw blade and can be 3mm for a typical saw blade or as small as 1.2mm for a thin-cut specialty blade. Either create saw kerf models to attach to each rectangle, or add the dimensions to each part as you create them.

Even though it can be fun to use TinkerCad for this project, SketchUp is better suited, in my opinion, as you would be able to add the necessary kerf lines to each rectangle, for easier reference and would be able to print out documents as necessary for the person making the cuts to use as reference.

I enjoy challenges of this nature and would be willing to create the documents in SketchUp if you care to provide the saw kerf dimension.

Keep in mind that there is likely no single perfect answer. Your parts list is quite varied and allows for many solutions. UPS delivery services has software to direct the driver to the best route for package delivery, but there does not appear to be an easy software package for this application.

Years ago, my boss decided to re-arrange the furniture in the communications room. Certain components could not be moved. Lacking computers so many years ago, he drew on graph paper the floor layout, as well as graph paper cut-outs for the tables and cabinets which could be moved. We were able to distract him and created a photo-copy of the floor layout, shrunk by 20 percent, preventing the previously arranged paper cut-outs from fitting as before. Our inability to stop laughing eventually clued him in on the prank.

You could, of course, use the graph paper panel and graph paper cut-outs for your pieces to accomplish a similar goal. Keep the saw kerf dimension at the forefront, or you will have an expensive sizing and cutting failure.